# Pentomino Validator

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem

As someone who can't be bothered to look at their pentominos to see if it makes a rectangular shape, I've decided to make you write a program that does it.

## Your task

Given some input split by newlines containing 12 unique characters, decide if it is a valid solution.

A valid solution MUST

- Have 5 of each character (except newlines)
- Each set of characters must be fully connected
- Each set of characters must have a unique shape
- Be in a regular rectangular shape

If it is a valid solution, output a truthy value, otherwise output a falsy value.

Your program may be a function or a full program but must take the input from stdin and output to stdout.

### Test cases

Valid solutions

```
000111
203331
203431
22 444
2   46
57 666
57769!
58779!
58899!
5889!!

00.@@@ccccF111//=---
0...@@c))FFF1//8===-
00.ttttt)))F1/8888=-
```

Invalid configurations

```
invalid (doesn't contain 12 unique characters)

111112222233333444445555566666
77777888889999900000qqqqqwwwww (Each set has the same shape)

1234567890qw
w1234567890q
qw1234567890
0qw123456789
90qw12345678 (None of the characters are connected)

1234567890qw (Not 5 characters in every set)

1111122222333334444455555666666
77777888889999900000qqqqqwwwwww (More than 5 characters in some sets)

00
0                   
00.@@@ccccF111//=---
 ...@@c))FFF1//8===-
  .ttttt)))F1/8888=- (Doesn't form a rectangular shape)
```

Comment: 1. Does a reflection of a pentomino have the same shape as the original? 2. Can we assume the input will consist of printable ASCII characters and newlines?

Comment: @Dennis Yes and Yes

Comment: @DigitalTrauma It's not remotely a duplicate of that. BTW that was an awesome question, it's a shame I didn't have time to answer it when it was newly asked.

Comment: @steveverill you're right - I didn't read this question properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>237</s> <s>235</s> 222 bytes

```js
f=p=>(m=[],s=[],d=0,l=p.indexOf`
`+1,[...p].map((c,i)=>(i+1)%l&&!m[i]?g=d-2<s.indexOf((t=a=>m[a]|p[a]!=c?r=0:(m[a]=y.push(a),n=a<n?a:n,t(a+1)+t(a-1)+t(a+l)+t(a-l)+1))(n=i,y=[])!=5?g=0:s[d++]=y.map(a=>r+=a-n)|r):0),d==12&g)
```

2 bytes saved thanks to [@DankMemes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20666/dankmemes)!

### Usage

```js
f(`000111
203331
203431
22 444
2   46
57 666
57769!
58779!
58899!
5889!!`);
=> true
```

### Explanation

A couple of notes about this solution:

- It's possible this answer is not valid. It does not actually check if rotated pentominoes are the same shape, however I tried but could not find a valid pentomino rectangle that meets the requirements in the rules and includes two or more of the same shape rotated. But I'm no pentomino expert so if you find a valid combination that this fails with, let me know.
- The rules also require answers to use `STDIN` and `STDOUT` for input and output but `prompt()` is only designed for single line input and my (Windows) computer automatically puts `\r\n` characters at every new line when pasting so I made it a function that accepts a string.

```js
f=p=>(
  m=[],                      // m = map of checked characters
  s=[],                      // s = list of shapes found (stored as integer)
  d=0,                       // d = number shapes found
  l=p.indexOf`
`+1,                         // l = length of each line (including newline character)
  [...p].map((c,i)=>         // iterate through each character of the input
    (i+1)%l&&                // skip newline characters
      !m[i]?                 // skip the character if it has already been mapped
        g=                   // g = pentomino is valid
          d-2<s.indexOf(     // check if shape already existed before just now
            (t=a=>           // t() checks if character is part of the shape then maps it
              m[a]|          // skip if character is already mapped
                p[a]!=c      //    or if the current character is part of the shape
              ?r=0:(
                m[a]=        // mark the character as mapped
                  y.push(a), // y = list of shape character indices
                n=a<n?a:n,   // n = minimum index of all characters in the shape
                t(a+1)+      // check and map adjacent characters
                t(a-1)+
                t(a+l)+
                t(a-l)+
                1
              )
          )(n=i,y=[])
            !=5?g=0:         // make sure there are only 5 characters in the shape
            s[d++]=          // add the shape to the list
              y.map(a=>      // sum of (index of each character in the shape - minimum
                r+=a-n)|r    //     index) = unique integer representing the shape
        ):0
  ),
  d==12&g                    // ensure there is 12 shapes and return the 'is valid' result
)
```

Comment: You can abuse tagged templates with `l=p.indexOf\`<newline here>\`` to save 2 bytes

Comment: @DankMemes Thanks for the catch! I was really tired when I wrote this and I haven't double checked it yet. :P